# Is the Acer Swift 5 laptop fit for Android development?

Tags: laptop, android, development, game-development

I will buy a new laptop for some development purposes. My currently laptop lags so freaking much as once opening an AVD (Android Emulator) it freezes.

My objective is currently Android and AI development, but later on I would probably do game development too.

I am considering this [Acer Swift 5 SF514-54T 2019](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/model/NX.HHUAA.001) [vendor link](https://www.amazon.in/Acer-SF514-54T-i7-1065G7-processor-Integrated/dp/B082FHZW6V). As from specs I see these important features that actually impressed me:

1. 12 hour battery life
2. [10th gen core i7 processor 1.3GHz (upto 3.9GHz Turbo)](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/196597/intel-core-i7-1065g7-processor-8m-cache-up-to-3-90-ghz.html)
3. 16 GB of DDR4X ram, 512 GB SSD
4. 989 grams of weight
5. Touch IPS display

The only downside I saw about this is that it does not comes with a dedicated Graphic card. It comes with *Intel Iris Plus Graphics* from the APU.

So will this laptop work for my case, won't it? I think not having a dedicated graphic card might actually result in lag, but I am not entirely sure if it will or not? So question is will it run smoothly?

If not, what are other laptops available with a dedicated graphic card, competing with the Acer Swift 5?

Comment: @Md. Rejaul Karim I didn't buyed it yet, question is in the last paragraph, if it will support android emulating system without the lag

Comment: Just taking suggestion that if it work for this case or need to find some other laptop with a dedicated graphic card.

Comment: Because i heard of that android and neural networks require GPUs.

Comment: Please read the question completly before downvoting!

Comment: If you want recommendations more specific to you, it may help to list a budget, and your general location (which appears to be india). As far as the current laptop you're considering, it will probably run fine as virtual machines are typically cpu/mem and disk bound. You can probably get away without having a dedicated GPU if you aren't doing graphics intensive android development.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using Android Studio, yes, the laptop will work well for it. My only concern would be that the laptop may run hot or even overheat because I don't see any large cooling fans on the CPU/GPU, but other than that concern, it would work well.

It meets all of the requirements for Android Studio:

Requirements:
OS: Microsoft Windows 7 or higher
RAM: 4GB
Disk: 2GB of available disk space
Screen Resolution: 1280 x 800p

Recommended:
OS: Windows 10
RAM: 8GB
Disk: 8GB or more
Screen Resolution: 1920 x 1080p

The Acer Swift 5 SF514-54T (2019):
OS: Windows 10
RAM: 16GB
Disk: 500GB
Screen Resolution: 1920 * 1080p (Full HD/FHD)

Comment: As since my current laptop lags on android emulator, i asked for that will this laptop run the emulator smoothly without the lag.

Comment: You didn't even cover the main topic of the graphics, i didn't saw any graphic recommendation in the official site, thats why i asked the question here.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu I would say it depends on what apps you plan on designing. If you plan on building something else but high-intensity games (like Asphalt 9 or Fortnite style games) and are going to make a simple break-the-lock style game or a social media style app, I would say you would be fine with the Intel Iris GPU. What is your budget so I can look around for laptops with dedicated GPU? If you go for a laptop with a dedicated GPU, you're going to suffer on battery life unless you tell the laptop to run the Intel/AMD integrated 24/7 except for when using the Android dev studio.